# Is mybatis method `BaseBuilder#parseExpression(...)` used?

Tags: mybatis

mybatis has the method:

`org.apache.ibatis.builder.BaseBuilder#parseExpression(String regex, String defaultValue)`

Is this method not used? Is it for subsequent expansion?

```
protected Pattern parseExpression(String regex, String defaultValue) {
    return Pattern.compile(regex == null ? defaultValue : regex);
}
```

Comment: Maybe it would be more helpful if you explain what you are trying to achieve? That method is not used anymore internally. But is there something from it that you would like?

Comment: @h3adache Although this method will be called internally, it can't see other functions. Mybatis source code is not used.